# How do I find the interval of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose I have: $$\sum \cfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}x^n$$

If I use the ratio test, I get $$\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}|x|$$

Why can it be said the radius of convergence here is $1$? Disregard the inclusion/exclsuion of the end-points - I am not worried about that.

---

Another example.

$$\sum \cfrac{n^2}{1+n}x^n$$

Using ratio test - we get $$x\cfrac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{2}{n}}(1+\cfrac{1}{n})^2$$

Why  is the ROC now $1$?

---

Also, when we solve these things, what can we say about differentiability and continuity?

Comment: Take the limit for $n\to\infty$ and check that $|\text{ratio}|<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have $x\in\mathbb{R}$, although the following arguments hold for $x\in\mathbb{C}$ as well (slight changes as we won't look at the intervall of convergence, but that isn't important right now).

Using the ratio test for $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} x^n$$ we get $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac 1n}}|x|=|x|.$$
You forgot to take the limit.

Now: the series converges if the result of the ratio test is $<1$ and it diverges if it is $>1$. Thus we can say that it converges for all $|x|<1$ and it diverges for all $|x|>1$. We can't say anything about $x=\pm 1$, you'd have to check these by hand. The same goes for your other series.

Once you have the radius/intervall of convergence, you can define a function $$f: I\rightarrow \mathbb R,x\mapsto \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n.$$ This function will be continous and differentiable for every $x\in I$.